# mongodb vs apache DB (Derby) or Java DB

Tags: derby, mongodb-java, javadb

Want to develop an application based on NoSQL DB.
I found apache DB, JavaDB & MongoDB are mostly used NoSQL Db's.
So I want to know what is the difference between these NoSQL DB's. I want to develop a web application. So which DB would be better to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference is that:

- "JavaDB" and "Apache DB" and Derby are the same
- Derby is a very SQL standards-compliant database, and thus hardly a NoSQL DB